# Difficulty getting good ranking in Google

Tags: seo, google-ranking

I have a new website that offers a collection of free sheet music. It currently has 300 pages of individual pieces of music.

I am having difficulty getting the index page to rank competitively in google search results. I wonder if anyone can see something I am obviously missing?

Here is the link to the index page:

https://www.bandit-scores.com

Comment: Question - Is the content better than the equivalent ranking content for the phrase you want to rank? Have you applied on-page SEO for that term? It's difficult to answer without knowing what you're trying to rank the content for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The index page must be ranked for search terms like "free sheet music" or "free music scores". I have used these search terms in page titles, headings etc. The individual tier 3 sheet music pages do rank well, but it is just the index page that I cannot get to rank well.